# How to use the token received from post request inside another upcoming put request? (React, JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, async-await, ecmascript-5

I am sending post request with some params and should get token. The question is how can I use that token inside another put request which is coming after that post request?

```
 async authorize () {
      try {
      
      await Service.auth.sendData(
      // some params that should be sent for getting token
        )

     const { products, comments } = await Service.products.getProducts(
         token: token,
         //other params

    
        )
```

token in the second await should be taken from first sendData post request's response. How can be it done correctly?

Comment: It depends on Service.auth.sendData implementation but if it returns a token just assign it to variable `const token = await Service.auth.sendData(...)`

Comment: @Rostyslav clarification: "*… returns a promise for a token …*"

Comment: @Bergi can you demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: @Rostyslav it's simple post request and I send data after which I should get token from it's response. Will your comment work in that case?

Comment: @Dave I mean what Rostyslav meant. Did you try it? We can't tell whether it will work unless you show us the code of `auth.sendData`.